# Subscribe to property value change

Tags: angularjs

in my Angular controller I have an array of object with certain properties.

```
$scope.myArray = [{prop1: "2435", prop2: "4534", propBool: false}, ...];
```

I bound this array property to generate rows in a table.
Then `prop1` and `prop2` are bound to text input fields and the `propBool` to a checkbox.

```
<td ng-hide="completeSelectedTripsStep == 0" style="width: 35px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chkProcessTrip" value="" ng-model="t.processTrip" 
                                ng-checked="{{ t.editPickupHour.length > 0 && t.editPickupMinute.length > 0 }}"/>
                        </td>
```

What I need, is when user types something in BOTH text fields and values are not empty string to automatically check he chekbox.

I tried to use the $watch method of the $scope object but it doesn't work.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Dont interpolate within an Angular directive, it does that for you - `ng-checked="condition"` and it should work.

Comment: that's what I did, see my sample code, but it won't work.

Comment: You are using `{{}}` in an `ng-directive` - don't

Comment: yeah, that was it. Works now!!

Comment: Awesome, I just posted a quick answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're writing within an `ng-directive` you do not need to include the `{{}}` to interpolate -- angular takes care of this. So change your `ng-checked` to:

```html
ng-checked="t.editPickupHour.length > 0 && t.editPickupMinute.length > 0"
```